# Facebook authenticated referrals is gone.. What now?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have to create a new simple Facebook application. Everything was great until I wanted to configure the app Permissions. The "Authenticated referrals" option is disappeared. Maybe it is an amature question, but.. what now? I configured everything, and the Auth Dialog doesnt show up, so the application doesnt ask for any permission.

I have to access the users:

- email
- likes

and I have to publish a photo to his/her profile.

How can I get permissions now? I tried to find out on the developer blog but I found nothing usefull.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using PHP and since you didn't mention using Javascript, this is [the server-side flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/), step four is where you specify the permissions (using the `scope` parameter):

```
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=email,publish_stream,user_likes";

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }
```

For the list of permissions, refer to the [permissions document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions).

Answer (score 0):

The removal of Authenticated Referrals in February 2013 shouldn't affect existing your [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) code at all - the authenticated referrals settings only applied to one specific login flow, which was users on facebook clicking links to content posted by the app

ifaour's examples shows a very simple example of using the server side Oauth flow, but your code should probably already have looked like that or it would have failed in the non-authenticated-referrals flows